# Trigger Gitlab pipeline in a definite day/time

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I have Gitlab pipeline triggering on each merge in other project. Now I would like to trigger pipeline regularly, let's say, each day at the same time or once a week. Is there any way to set schedule this way?

Comment: GitLab provides a feature called "Scheduled Pipelines" that allows you to run a pipeline at specified intervals, such as daily or weekly. Isn't that what you looking for? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, like a [scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html)?

It's under "CI/CD":

- Pipelines
- Editor
- Jobs
- Schedules

EDIT:
Use "Custom" for "Interval Pattern" and specify it with Crontab notation:

```
*       *    *             *     *
minute hour day(of month) month day(of week)
```

For example if you wanted at 4am every Wednesday, then it's `0 4 * * 3`

Comment: And how to set the exact job that will br triggered in this case?

Comment: You set your schedule under the CI/CD options of the repo that you want the pipeline to run.  You set the target branch/tag, etc. so your `.gitlab-ci.yml` will run the steps accordingly based on that.